# how to send data on a modal and use it on foreach

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

I bet thats is not possible but id like to try to ask...

I'm on blade/laravel/bootstrap4 page, and id like to open a modal with some data that are in the button context, but i cannot understand how to popolate the modal.

My button is like:

```
@foreach($workflows as $workflowId => $tasks)
                                <button type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-primary bottoneblu"
                                        data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#exampleModal"
                                        data-title="{{$workflowId}}"
                                        data-tasks="{{json_encode($tasks)}}">

                                </button>
@endforeach
```

And then some jquery to achieve the goal:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
                $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal

                    var title = button.data('title')
                    var tasks = button.data('tasks')

                    var modal = $(this)
                    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Workflow numero: ' + title)
                })
            });
```

and the related modal should be like:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                       @foreach (json_decode($tasks as $task)
                                {{$task->something}}
                       @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the Title part work yet, what isnt clear to me if its possible, is passing "$tasks" and using it, without a form or a redirect via http or adding dozen of data-something on the button part.
Even because tasks can be, 1 or many...so i cannot populate it on the button field by field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not evaluate the task json object within the modal template, but within the `show.bs.modal` event handler.

Get rid of this part:

```
@foreach (json_decode($tasks as $task)
  {{$task->something}}
@endforeach
```

and add this to your event handler :

```
$.each(tasks, function() {
    modal.find('.modal-body').append( this.something );
});
```

Comment: maybe i wrong to not tell that there is a complex html structure that should be populated with this data, each task have a div with a lot of field, and how many divs depends on how many tasks are present, so i cannot have a empty layout   to be populated. i hope to be enough clear

Comment: That doesnt change alot tbh. You can either create that html within the `$.each()` or use something like [jQuery loadTemplate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.loadtemplate) to populate the body (but then you could create the whole modal with that). I'm not familiar with laravel but worked alot with ZendFramework. There your could render such an html view server side and return the whole html. But you shouldnt mix that. Do it either the one or the other way.